# Ordering in desc order and setting document limit in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to add query params that allow the api user to have the option to sort by descending order based on the title field and to limit the the amount items the query returns.  But when I call the endpoint it still just returns the data unsorted and without the limit applied to it.

```
getCourses = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const limit = req.query.limit | 20;
    if (req.query.desc === "true") {
      const data = await courseModel.find().sort({ title: -1 }).limit(limit);
      return res.json(data);
    } else {
      const data = await courseModel.find().aggregate({ $limit: limit });
      return res.json(data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};


const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    length: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

const CourseMessge = mongoose.model('CourseMessage', courseSchema);

module.exports = CourseMessge
```

This is how i am calling the end point:
localhost:3000/api/courses?desc=true&limit=10

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `||` operator for specifying a default value for the `limit`.
Also, try to cast the `desc` parameter to a string:

```
getCourses = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const limit = req.query.limit || 20;
    if (req.query.desc.toString() === 'true') {
      const data = await courseModel.find().sort({ title: -1 }).limit(limit);
      return res.json(data);
    } else {
      const data = await courseModel.find().limit(limit);
      return res.json(data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```